# How to auto resize width of ui-grid with a flex layout

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I'm trying to make the auto-resize directive work but i have an unexpected behavior when the width of the container is shrinking. The ui-grid is not shrinking (it works on expand).

Here is a plunker of my app layout with the problem i'm facing :

http://plnkr.co/edit/IjV4RbEQmkJFBH5t?preview

If i add a `width: 100% !important` to the `grid` class the grid start expanding without ever stopping.

Do i have to rewrite the auto-resize directive or is there an other way with css ?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Comment: There is a plnkr link with a full example, you doesn't have access to it ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code so not sure what you're trying to do.

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.resize {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Using `flex: 1 1 auto` on a child where a parent has `display: flex` will have it automatically expand to fit the parent.

Comment: You cannot see the plunker code ?
This is what i have done on the parent container of the ui-grid but the ui-grid doesn't follow the flex rule.